# RecursionError in Python Using Hylang

Tags: python, recursion, lisp, the-little-schemer, hy

First off let me just say I know what I'm doing is not ideal, but I'm trying to write the member? function from [*The Little Schemer*](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/little-schemer-fourth-edition) using Hy.

```
(setv else True)

(defn null? [lst]
  " If list is empty return True else False "
  (if lst
      False
      True))


(defn member? [a lat]
  " Checks if value is a member of a list "
  (cond
    [(null? lat) False]
    [else (or (= (first lat) a)
              (member? a (rest lat)))]))

(print (member? 1 '(2 3 4 1)))
```

This works exactly how I expect. The problem is, if the list is greater than 4 elements long I get the error

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I know Python isn't meant to do recursion and in [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) it even says that there is a default recursion limit to keep the C stack from overflowing. On my machine `getrecursionlimit()` yields the value of 1000, and I was able to successfully set it to over 20,000 before getting a segfault. Even with it set to 20,000 I am still getting the error on a list of 5 elements. What I don't understand is... How am I hitting over 20,000 levels of recursion on a 5 element list?

And for those curious I'm using Python 3.6.5, MacOS Mojave version 10.14.6 on a 15" Macbook pro, Hylang version 0.18.0, and the output of my program using hy2py is

```
from hy.core.language import first, rest
from hy import HyExpression, HyInteger
hyx_else = True


def is_null(lst):
    """ If list is empty return True else False """
    return False if lst else True


def is_member(a, lat):
    """ Checks if value is a member of a list """
    return False if is_null(lat) else first(lat) == a or is_member(a, rest(lat)
        ) if hyx_else else None


print(is_member(1, HyExpression([] + [HyInteger(2)] + [HyInteger(3)] + [
    HyInteger(4)] + [HyInteger(5)] + [HyInteger(1)])))
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't reproduce this on Hy master. It's probably a bug that was fixed since 0.18.0.